# Find all without association through association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join, associations

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :users
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :campaign
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts, :join_table => "users_posts"
  belongs_to :campaign
end
```

If user saw this post I add him to post.users. I need find first unwatched post of user campaign. Smth like this:

```
current_user.campaign.posts.where('posts.users not include current_user')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MrYoshiji, Thanks a lot! You remember me about `include`. Before I tried `join` and it did not work with nil because `INNER JOIN`, I solved my problem with instance method:

```
  def unwatched_post
    campaign.posts.includes(:users).where('users.id != ? OR users.id IS NULL', self.id).first
  end
```